# test Plone passwords strength

Tags: security, authentication, passwords, cryptography

I am performing a penetration test on a Plone site. Is there any tool to assess the password's strength, once I have the passwords (hashed with SSHA)?

Thanks and regards, 
Grig

Comment: This isn't a Plone-specific question, so I removed the plone tag.

Comment: sha/ssha is a hash function not an encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have the hash, then the only assessment you can make is by trying to guess the exact password, which is kind of expensive. And then, either you break it, or not; there is no middle ground. You could use the *time* it took you to guess the password as an estimate for the password strength, but, hopefully, good passwords will take a longer time than is practical. That's the point of hashing passwords: so that guessing the password and verifying it with the hash is a matter of weeks or months, not minutes.

As part of a penetration test, if you have the hashed passwords, then you should run a [password cracker](http://sectools.org/crackers.html). You may have to develop a bit of software if the exact password hash process is not already integrated. Any broken password would be reported as a severe system weakness.

Usual password strength estimators operate on the unhashed password, by trying to determine how much guessable the password is. This does not work very well in practice, because "guessing" may involve human brains, which evade accurate modelling. For instance, you can make a long password by concatenating four or five dates (e.g. in the YYMMDD format); such a password will be estimated to have a good strength -- but if the dates are the birth dates of your wife and children, then chances are that the password is actually easy to guess.

Answer (score 0):

No.

If I understand you correctly, you are proposing to supply the hypothesized tool with a hash rather than the cleartext password itself.  I am reasonably confident in this conjecture:  a tool as you describe it will tell more about the SSHA encryption than the strength of the underlying password.

I'll say this in a positive way:  a tool to assess password strength operates on the plaintext password; otherwise, it measures mostly the entropy of the hashing method.

There's no particular Plone content to my claims, of course.  To build a Plone (or Zope ...) product based on one of the existing password strength-checkers should, of course, be straightforward.  I'm aware of none that have been packaged for the public.

Answer (score 0):

SSHA or more commonly known as a salted sha1 is a good method of storing passwords.  SHA1 is technically broken but no one has generated a collision and it is still on the list NIST recommended message digest functions.

[John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) can be used to break salted sha1 hashes.

A salted SHA256 would be a better choice.

Comment: Note that known weaknesses on SHA-1 have no impact here. Password hashing works on preimage resistance, not collision resistance, and, as far as we know, SHA-1 is still as solid as ever against preimages. In practice, the salting process (the way the salt is inserted, and how many repetitions and iterations are involved) is way more important. Using SHA-256 is still recommended, if only because it avoids getting comments about how "SHA-1 is broken".

Comment: @Thomas Pornin A hash function that has a collision weakness can be faster to brute force because X number of rounds are unnecessary  (http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-09/BEVAND/BHUSA09-Bevand-MD5-SLIDES.pdf)